# A kind of transform in pandas

Tags: pandas, transform, reshape

Given a sample dataframe with one row like this:

```
brand_1 gen_1   both_1  brand_2 gen_2   both_2  brand_3 gen_3   both_3
6133    5636    5446    0       3239    0           6032    5870    5484
```

Transpose or Transform does not work in my attempt to produce the following reshaping of this data:

```
Type    Brand    Gen    Both
1       6133     5636   5446
2       0        3239   0
3       6032     5870   5484
```

I have tried both Transform and Transpose along with iloc on chunks of columns, but no result reshapes the data this way.  Hence, my question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us try `wide_to_long`

```
out = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['brand','gen','both'],i=['index'],j='Type',sep='_').reset_index()
Out[135]: 
   index  Type  both_susp_2  brand   gen    both
0      0     1            0   6133  5636  5446.0
1      0     2            0      0  3239     NaN
2      0     3            0   6032  5870  5484.0
```

Comment: After seeing your response, noticed a small typo in my original sample dataframe.  That column both_susp_2 should have just read 'both_2' to be consistent.  Still, I will try your answer and update.

Comment: your code produced an empty dataframe on my actual data unfortunately.  Still reviewing to ensure I used it correctly.

Comment: @JohnTaylor you may try ` pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['brand','gen','both'],i=['index'],j='Type',sep='_', suffix = '\w+').reset_index()`

Comment: Wow, so that worked perfectly.  So, appreciate your time in setting that out for me.  @BENY

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
 # install latest dev version
 # pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git

 import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index = None, 
                names_to = ('.value', 'Type'), 
                names_sep = '_')

  Type  brand   gen  both
0    1   6133  5636  5446
1    2      0  3239     0
2    3   6032  5870  5484
```

The `.value` serves as an indicator; parts of the column name that aligns with `.value`(brand, gen, both) stay as column names, while the parts that align with `Type` become values in the new column `Type`.